# php regex not working while working on regex101

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here is my code. I am trying to match this string with my regex but it fails everytime on my local xampp server and my dedicated server. Surprsingly when i test this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rk3UG2/2) it works there somehow. Why ??

```
<?php

$str = "80 ×× ×× ×× ×× ××
×× ×× 91 94 ×× ××
";

echo strlen($str);

if (preg_match("/[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}/", $str)) {
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "no mto";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your regex is confusing. What do you want to do?

Comment: I have match code something like in the string but they varies everytime

Comment: You can simplify it to `[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}(?:[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}){4}`

Comment: @chris85 I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `u` modifier to enable the unicode mode for regular expressions, since that `×` character in subject and pattern is *not* within the ASCII character range. Note the trailing `/u` in the pattern definition:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOT

80 ×× ×× ×× ×× ××
×× ×× 91 94 ×× ××

EOT;

if (preg_match("/[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}[ \[\]().]{1,3}[0-9*+=\-#@×?]{2,3}/u", $str)) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "no mto";
}
```

The output obviously is:

```
ok
```